# Using a parent's website login for a child site : best practice?

Tags: asp.net, html, authentication, webforms

We have already a main site with a login.
We'd like to open a child site from the main site using the main's site login.

In the web world, what's the best practice to pass along the login details in a very safe way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the best practice, but when I had to do something similar for two internal websites, I just did it through an access token.

So the user will click a link on the main site which will create a database record in a table that contains at the very least their username, an expiration date, and a GUID.

We then redirect them to the child site using something like `http://childsite.aspx?token=GUID`

The child site looks up the GUID (if the querystring exists), validates that it's valid/not expired, and if it is valid set the authorization for that username and delete the record from the database.

Nothing gets passed along except a GUID. Which is useless once it's been used once, and it can only be created by a user who has already authenticated.

This works if the sites access a common database. I'm assuming that they do since your question implies that the login credentials for the main site are valid on the child site as well.

Comment: Yes, we could use the same Users\Login database for both sites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what should I search online for a more technical explanation of the access token with GUID ?

Comment: What do you mean by technical explanation? An access token is just what I call the GUID. You can call it whatever you want, but if you want an explanation as to what a GUID is, look it up on Wikipedia. The basics is that it is just a unique identifier that is impossible for someone to guess. Which is why I'd use it over an integer.

Comment: Oh okay, and I guess there's .NET libs to decode the GUID and retrieve the original username\passwd to use in the child site ?

Comment: @TommyLeblanc, there is no decoding, because a GUID is not encoded in the first place. It's just a unique identifier. In C#, you'd call `System.Guid guid = System.Guid.NewGuid;` to generate one. Then just store that in the database and query for it later.